# DataFrame: How to toggle a cell value base on another cell of the row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of friends attending my party:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], 'is_here': [True, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**Question:** How can I toggle the `is_here` boolean based on a given name? (e.g. how to make `toggle('Charlie')` turns the `False` into `True` in my DataFrame?)

---

I can get one's status as a boolean using `df[df['name'] == 'Charlie'].iloc[0]['is_here']`, but I struggle changing the value in `df`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Toggle `Charlie` with `xor`

```
df.loc[df.name.eq('Charlie'), 'is_here'] ^= True

df

   is_here     name
0     True    Alice
1     True      Bob
2     True  Charlie
```

---

### Explanation

Only one can be True
Truth Table for `xor`

```
       x      y  x ^ y
0   True   True  False
1   True  False   True
2  False   True   True
3  False  False  False
```

So:
if `x = True`, `x ^ True` evaluates to `False`
if `x = False`, `x ^ True` evaluates to `True`

Using `^=` on the `loc`, we take the `xor` with `True` for all elements represented with the slice and assign the results in place.

Answer (score 3):

You can using `set_index` + `.loc`

```
df.set_index('name',inplace=True)
df.loc['Alice']
Out[164]: 
is_here    True
Name: Alice, dtype: bool
```

Update

```
df.loc[df.name=='Charlie','is_here']=True
df
Out[176]: 
   is_here     name
0     True    Alice
1     True      Bob
2     True  Charlie
```

Update 2

```
df.loc[df.name=='Charlie','is_here']=~df['is_here']
df
Out[185]: 
   is_here     name
0     True    Alice
1     True      Bob
2     True  Charlie
```

Answer (score 3):

**To update your mapping**

```
df = df.set_index('name')
df.loc['Charlie', 'is_here'] = ~df.loc['Charlie', 'is_here']

print(df.reset_index())

#       name  is_here
# 0    Alice     True
# 1      Bob     True
# 2  Charlie     True
```

---

**To query your mapping**

From your dataframe:

```
ishere = df.set_index('name')['is_here'].get

print(ishere('Alice'))  # True
```

From your original dictionary:

```
ishere = dict(zip(d['name'], d['is_here'])).get

print(ishere('Alice'))  # True
```